# Linearity of a 1-relator group obtained by adjunction of a square root to an element in a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $F=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_d\rangle$ be a free group on $d$ variables. Let $w\in F$ be a word which is not a proper power in $F$.

> Is it known that the group $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_d,z| w=z^2\rangle$ is linear over a field?

Comment: This group is hyperbolic by standard combination theorems and virtually compact special by Wise's theorem "Special hyperbolic amalgams" from his manuscript about groups with quasiconvex hierarchy. Hence it is linear over the integers.

Comment: @AshotMinasyan What about the degrees of linear representations (over a field) of these groups? Can they be bounded uniformly (independently on $w$)?

Comment: I am afraid that the method I suggested does not give any bounds on the degree of a faithful linear representation.